# Server connected, but no response TCP socket programming

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, tcp, dht

I'm implementing a circular distributed hash table, each peer knows its immediate successor and set up TCP connection with its successor, like, 1->3->4->5->8->1.

User will input a 4-digit number, and we proceed it into a certain value using a hash function written by us. For example, user inputs 3456, corresponding hash value is 128. Peer 3 get the input from user, and pass the hash value to its successor(4) asking if he is greater than hash value. If not, the successor will pass the hash to its successor(5). Repeat this until it find the right peer. (Here, since 8 < 128, we say peer 1 is the one we want)

Now, we know peer 1 is the peer we want. Then we let peer 1 make a TCP connection with the requesting peer 3, and send 3 "FIND1,3456,3", when peer 3 get this message, it should print out "peer 1 has the value".

The problem I met is, after I find peer 1 is the one I want, my peer 1 client sets up TCP connection with peer 3 server (peer 1 client said the connection is set up), but peer 3 doesn't get any message from peer 1, what's wrong with it?

How should I fix it?

Thanks for your patience to read these, feel free to ask if there is anything ambiguous :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import sys
import socket
import time
import threading
import re
from collections import defaultdict

successor = defaultdict(dict)

peer = int(sys.argv[1])
successor[1] = int(sys.argv[2])
successor[2] = int(sys.argv[3])

serverName = 'localhost'
peerPort = 50000 + int(peer)
address = (serverName,peerPort)

#-------------proceed input string---------------------------
def getFileNum(name):
    fileValid = re.match('^request ([0-9]{4})$',name) 
    if fileValid is None:
        print 'invalid file!'
        return
    else:
        hashName = fileValid.group(1)
        return hashName
#----------------get request input--------------------------------
def getRequestInput(clientSocketTCP):
    while flag == 0:
            fileName = raw_input()
        hashname = getFileNum(fileName)
        if hashname is not None:
            hashname = re.sub('^(0)*','',hashname)
            hashnum = int(hashname) % 256
            info = 'FILE_REQUEST'+str(hashname) + ','+ str(hashnum) + ','+ str(peer) + ',1'
            clientSocketTCP.send(info)
            print 'File request message for '+ str(hashname) + ' has been sent to my successor.'
    clientSocketTCP.close()
#-------------------send file to successor---------------------------
def sendRequestToS(clientSocketTCP):
    global important
    while flag == 0:
        if important: 
                an = re.match('^FILE_REQUEST([0-9]{4}),',important)
            if an:
                hashname = an.group(1)
                clientSocketTCP.send(important)
                            print 'File request message for '+ str(hashname) + ' has been sent to my successor.'
                important = ''
    clientSocketTCP.close()
#-----------------------find file-------------------------------------
def findF():
    global flag
    global important
    while flag == 0:
        if re.match('^FIND',important):
            obj = re.match('^FIND[0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{4}),([0-9]{1,3})',important)
            n = int(obj.group(2))
            info = important
            ff = threading.Thread(target=clientTCPTemp,args=(n,info))
            ff.start()
            ff.join()
            important = ''


#--------------------set up client temporary---------------------------
def clientTCPTemp(n,info):
    global flag
    clientConn = False
    clientSocketTCP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serverPortTCP = 50000 + n
    print serverPortTCP
    while not clientConn:
        try:
            clientSocketTCP.connect((serverName,serverPortTCP))
            clientConn = True
            print "Now client connection works!!!!!"
        except:
            print "fail"
    clientSocketTCP.send(info)
    print info
        print 'A response message, destined for peer '+ str(n) +', has been sent.'
    clientSocketTCP.close()


#--------------------TCP server---------------------------------------
def serverTCP():
    global flag
    global serverSetUp
    global important
    serverSocketTCP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serverConn = False
    while not serverConn:
        try:
            serverSocketTCP.bind((serverName,peerPort))
            serverConn = True
            serverSocketTCP.listen(2)
            serverSetUp = 0
            print 'The server is ready to receive'
        except:
            pass
    while flag == 0:
        connectionSocket, addr = serverSocketTCP.accept()
        print 'connect by'+ str(addr)
        threeinfo = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        print threeinfo
        if re.match('^FILE_REQUEST',threeinfo):
            obj = re.match('^FILE_REQUEST([0-9]{4}),([0-9]{1,3}),([0-9]{1,3}),([01])$',threeinfo)
            if obj is not None:
                filename = obj.group(1)
                hashn = int(obj.group(2))
                peerID = int(obj.group(3))
                endCircle = int(obj.group(4))
                if peer < hashn and endCircle: 
                    print 'File ' +filename +' is not stored here. '
                    important = threeinfo
                    if peer > successor[1]:
                            important = re.sub('1$','0',threeinfo)
                else:
                    print 'File '+ filename+' is here.' 
                    important = 'FIND'+str(peer)+','+ filename +','+ str(peerID)
        elif re.match('^FIND',threeinfo):
            dest = re.match('^FIND([0-9]{1,3}),([0-9]{4})','',threeinfo)
            fromP = dest.group(1)
            fileP = dest.group(2)
            print 'Received a response message from peer '+fromP+', which has the file '+fileP
            connectionSocket.send('i receive from you------------------------')

        print sen
        connectionSocket.send('can you hear me?')
        connectionSocket.close()

#--------------------TCP client----------------------------------------
def clientTCP(n):
    global flag
    global serverSetUp
    global important
    clientConn = False
#   while serverSetUp == 1:
#       pass
    clientSocketTCP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serverPortTCP = 50000 + n
    while not clientConn:
        try:
            clientSocketTCP.connect((serverName,serverPortTCP))
            clientConn = True
            print "Now client connection works!!!!!"
        except:
            pass
    try:
        rt = threading.Thread(target=getRequestInput,args=(clientSocketTCP,))
        sr = threading.Thread(target=sendRequestToS,args=(clientSocketTCP,))
        ff = threading.Thread(target=findF,args=())
        rt.start()
        sr.start()              
        ff.start()      
    except:
        print 'thread failed'
    sen = raw_input()
    clientSocketTCP.send(sen)
    m = clientSocketTCP.recv(1024)
    print m
    clientSocketTCP.close()

#----------------start thread---------------------------------
#------adapt from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.html --------
flag = 0
serverSetUp = 1
important = ''
findFile = False
try:
    serTCP = threading.Thread(target=serverTCP,args=())
    cliTCP = threading.Thread(target=clientTCP,args=(successor[1],))
    serTCP.start()
    cliTCP.start()
except:
    print "thread can not be set up"
while flag == 0:
    try:
        pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        flag = 1
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  Paste your working script directly into SO, highlight it, and press `{}` button (or CTRL-K).